# Best way to change "bob@???.???" to "bob@something.com" using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

What's the best way of doing this:

```
mail = "bob@something.com"
mail2 = mail.do_magic
# puts mail2 will return "bob@anotherwebsite.com"
```

I'm thinking regex of course, but is there another cool way? If not, how should I do it using regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand what you're asking, but couldn't you use regex like this?

```
irb(main):001:0> email = "bob@example.com"
=> "bob@example.com"
irb(main):002:0> email.gsub(/@[\w.]+/, '@something.com')
=> "bob@something.com"
```

Let me know I've missed something or if I'm not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: I totally forgot that you could use regex with gsub... I officially lost my mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help!  Keep in mind I threw that regex together fairly quickly, so there might be a better expression for doing the replace.

Comment: There are tons of validation on the email before getting to this action, so just catching the @ will work just fine, but good point for a future reader ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexps in strings indexes too:

```
email = "bob@example.com"
replace = "foobar.invalid"
email[/@.*/] = "@#{replace}"
```

If you don't want to modify `email`:

```
(new = email.dup)[/@.*/] = "@#{replace}"
p [email,new]  # => ["bob@example.com", "bob@foobar.invalid"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, avoiding regular expressions, is to split and join

```
new = [email.split('@').first, "foobar.invalid"].join('@')
```